# AWS - connect domain to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I'm trying to connect my domain (Route 53) to an EC2 Instance with an elastic IP. I uploaded some text index.html file to the instance (/home/ec2-user), but when I try to reach the domain, I get an error from the browser that the server is not reachable.
Here are some pics from my AWS:

- **Domain:**

[image: register]

- **EC2:**

[image]

- **DNS:**

[image: dns]

- **SERVER:**

[image: server]

What am I doing wrong? It should be pretty straightforward..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mask all the id and re-upload the screenshot, this screenshot will post a security threat to your site. 
Your problem is quite common, please check your security group ingress setting.

Comment: @mootmoot What should I change in those settings? I have radio boxes which I can choose between 4 different groups..

Comment: First try `nslookup vetevo.de` to verify that the domain is correctly resolving to the IP address. Regarding serving a website from the EC2 instance you have to do much more than just upload an HTML file. Do you actually have a web server like Apache or Nginx running on the instance? Do you have the ports open in the instance's firewall and Security Group? Also a server isn't going to serve a website from your ec2-user home directory.

Comment: @MarkB actually I assume he have the server setup

Comment: If you are not sure, please go through this documentation with a cheap t2.micro. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html

Comment: @mootmoot why assume that? The question specifically says all he did was copy a html file into the home directory on the server.

Comment: @MarkB  Agree.  LOL.  Because it is strange that a newbie will start playing around with Route 53 instead of using the normal open IP

Comment: I obviously have more than an index.html file. It was just for testing. I'll go through the documentation, but I still don't understand why it won't serve the server to the domain - the connection between the DNS and the Server is wrong. with nslookup vetevo.de im getting the right address

Comment: It seems you need more knowledge on DevOps.  `http://serverfault.com/` is the right place for your server questions.  E.g DNS server does NOT connect to any server, its primary purpose is translate hostname to IP address for people who request it. But let's solve your server deployment issues first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @MarkB hint, I assume you are totally new to AWS EC2.

For starter, you don't need Route53, until you are done with server configuration.

[Create an EC2 Instance and Install a Web Server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html) is a good documentation for starting. Under step 9, the security group for Inbound already shown as

```
http   TCP , port 80, allow 0.0.0.0/0
ssh    TCP , port 22, allow 0.0.0.0/0
```

(you can change allow 0.0.0.0/0 to your current internet IP address to restrict connection )
This setup will assign the EC2 with a auto-assigned AWS random public IP (that you don't need to pay as compare to EIP).

You can then SSH (and also doing scp) directly into this server using the private key assigned.  Anyway , this question should move to serverfault, which is more appropriate.